# Is it possible to subscribe websocket session on multiple websocket streams and controll subscriptions

Tags: java, websocket, spring-webflux

Want to realize functionality using Spring Web Flux. All application clients connect to client service via websocket. Then want to subscribe their sessions to websocket streams from another microservices and manage subscriptions according incoming messages.

```
@Component
public class ReactiveWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

@Override
@NotNull
public Mono<Void> handle(@NotNull WebSocketSession session) {
    final WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
    final URI url1 = URI.create("ws://another-service1");
    final URI url2 = URI.create("ws://another-service2");

    return session.receive()
            .doOnNext(message -> {
                final String command = message.getPayloadAsText();
                if (command.equals("subscribe sevice1")) {
                    // client.execute(url1, ...
                    // get flux stream from client invoke and start sending it to current session
                } else if (command.equals("subscribe sevice2")) {
                    // ...
                } else if (command.equals("unsubscribe sevice1")) {
                    // ...
                } else if (command.equals("unsubscribe sevice2")) {
                    // ...
                }
            })
            .then(); 
}
```

Is it possible to realize such logic using webflux?